# Populating QTableWidget from value

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm coming from a background of python and pyside. So I apologize for anything that may appear as an odd practice in C++.

[image]

Two questions:

1. I want to populate a table with a set of data which is currently a list of dictionaries, as seen in my original python code. How would this be translated into my C++ Qt project so i can populate my tablewidget using this data? It doesn't appear that Qt uses dictionaries like python, it uses QMap.
2. It looks like Qt uses a QMap variant, not dictionaries. I'm open to formatting the data differently if there is a more efficient way of doing so. Whatever will make it easy to save to a text file and at the same time load from a file it populate the ui. It's important to mention that this data will eventually be saved to a file and loaded from a file. That's why my old python project uses json as the format.

My goal is to eventually extend my subclass of QTableWidget to add methods for loading from a file and saving to a file. Similar to presets.

List of Dictionaries:

```
[
    {
        "key":"SHOT",
        "value":"",
        "description":"Current Shot node name",
    },
    {
        "key":"PASS",
        "value":"",
        "description":"Current Pass node name",
    },
    {
        "key":"SELF",
        "value":"",
        "description":"Current node name",
    },
    {
        "key":"MM",
        "value":"",
        "description":"Current month as integer ex: 12",
    },
    {
        "key":"DD",
        "value":"",
        "description":"Current day as integer ex: 07",
    }
]
```

cpp

```
#include "tokeneditor.h"
#include <QTableWidget>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

TokenEditor::TokenEditor(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    // Controls
    QTableWidget *ui_userTokens = new QTableWidget();

    // Layout
    QVBoxLayout * layout = new QVBoxLayout();
    layout->setMargin(0);
    layout->setSpacing(0);
    layout->addWidget(ui_userTokens);
    setLayout(layout);

    // populate table with data...
}
```

Comment: Qt has JSON support.

Comment: `QTableWidget *ui_userTokens = new QTableWidget();` you will have memory leaks if you don't set the parents.

Comment: You probably want a JSON model https://github.com/dridk/QJsonModel or maybe https://github.com/poulh/qjsontablemodel

Comment: @drescherjm how do i assign the parent when ill be eventually adding it into a gridlayout with a specific column/grid order?

Comment: Change `QVBoxLayout * layout = new QVBoxLayout();` to `QVBoxLayout * layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);`

Comment: @drescherjm and from there im fine to leave everything else as is? Thank you for your kind help on this. i appreciate it.

Comment: The layout will become the parent of `ui_userTokens`. Here is the info on that: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#addItem

Comment: After you add a JSON model you would switch your QTableWidget  to a QTableView and use http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#setModel

Comment: @drescherjm I'm assuming the json model would be ideal, since I'll eventually be making it possible for users to right-click an item in the table and Remove or Edit the item. Being slightly familiar with models from python, i can see why. If you were interested in helping me out i would gladly paypal you for your time. Would you be interested in that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179934/discussion-between-jokermartini-and-drescherjm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comments Qt supports Json, in the next part I show you an example, plus you should consider that C ++ gives freedom to handle memory so take into account in eliminating it if necessary, in the case of Qt many times it is give that responsibility to Qt through the kinship tree.

***.h**

```
#ifndef TOKENEDITOR_H
#define TOKENEDITOR_H

#include <QWidget>

class QTableWidget;

class TokenEditor : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit TokenEditor(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~TokenEditor();

private:
    QTableWidget *ui_userTokens;
};

#endif // TOKENEDITOR_H
```

***.cpp**

```
#include "tokeneditor.h"

#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QJsonArray>

#include <QTableWidget>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

TokenEditor::TokenEditor(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui_userTokens(new QTableWidget)
{
    const std::string json = R"([{
                             "key": "SHOT",
                             "value": "",
                             "description": "Current Shot node name"
                             },
                             {
                             "key": "PASS",
                             "value": "",
                             "description": "Current Pass node name"
                             },
                             {
                             "key": "SELF",
                             "value": "",
                             "description": "Current node name"
                             },
                             {
                             "key": "MM",
                             "value": "",
                             "description": "Current month as integer ex: 12"
                             },
                             {
                             "key": "DD",
                             "value": "",
                             "description": "Current day as integer ex: 07"
                             }
                             ])";

    QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(QByteArray::fromStdString(json));

    auto layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    layout->setMargin(0);
    layout->setSpacing(0);
    layout->addWidget(ui_userTokens);

    ui_userTokens->setRowCount(5);
    ui_userTokens->setColumnCount(3);
    ui_userTokens->setHorizontalHeaderLabels({"key", "value", "description"});

    int r=0;
    for(const QJsonValue & val : doc.array()){
        QJsonObject obj = val.toObject();
        int c=0;
        for(const QString & key: obj.keys()){
            auto *it = new QTableWidgetItem(obj[key].toString());
            ui_userTokens->setItem(r, c, it);
            c++;
        }
        r++;
    }
}

TokenEditor::~TokenEditor()
{
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your example on this eyllanesc, This is certainly helpful. Based on the users comments above, im assuming it would be beneficial to use a Model approach since I intend on making it possible for users to doubleclick a row item to change it's key and value, as well as remove items from the table by right-clicking and doing Edit or Remove. The edit would popupte a dialog with two fields pre-populated with Key and Value where the user can edit them and hit Ok or Cancel.

Comment: @eyllanesc, could you please explain what `R"` means. I haven't met this notation before and because of its syntax I don't get relevant results when I search for it.

Comment: @scopchanov read https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal

Comment: @eyllanesc, so it is something like `verbatim` in `LaTeX`. Do I understand it right?

Comment: @JokerMartini QTableWidget is a QTableView with a model, so in a certain way it is using the model but the objective of QTableWidget is that the developer does not know about it and can work without problems, for example the QTableWidget allows you to change the values but not the keys since there is no access or representation, in the end if you want to generate the json you just have to retrieve the QTableWidget and build it. If you want to edit the keys, your view should be a QTreeView or its equivalent a QTreeWidget.

Comment: @JokerMartini [cont] It will depend on how much customization I want to give you and your knowledge, I see that you know few models so I would recommend starting with a QTreeWidget. The right-click functionalities all views have since they inherit from QAbstractItemView.

Comment: @scopchanov you could say that if, for example with string literals you can use \ without placing \\.

Comment: @eyllanesc, I see. I didn't know that and it was helpful for me. Thank you very much!

Comment: @eyllanesc I emailed you about a question